# Настройка камеры в PixelArt игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

### Что нужно?

Я изучаю Unity3D на основе 2D pixelArt игры.
**Есть задача:** Правильно настроить ортографическую камеру.

**Я уже пробовал использовать:**

- Pixel Perfect Camera (preview-компонент)
- Собственный скрипт
- Камера без изменения orthographicSize

---

### Вопросы

Я до сих пор не совсем понимаю какое значение нужно использовать для Pixel Per Unit в моих спрайтах, чтобы добиться Pixel Perfect. Источники гугла заверяют, что это должен быть размер тайла, но если у меня спрайт не квадратный, к примеру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я добиваюсь Pixel Perfect Effect, то все мои спрайты становятся очень маленькими и в виду особенности рисовки (малая детализация пиксельных артов) это выглядит плохо, **как можно с этим справиться?** **Нужна ли эта Pixel Perfect графика?**
Выглядит Pixel Perfect вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я использую пустую камеру (без скриптов) при изменении разрешения экрана можно добиться вот такого неприятного эффекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Очень интересно услышать мнение каждого, кто как справлялся с этими проблемами.

Спасибо :)

Comment: Так и хочется спросить а какая разница, какой ppu, если вы в итоге спрайты скейлите, вертите и не округляете координаты объектов и камеры до целых чисел. Качественный пиксельарт не для начинающих.

Comment: @Yaroslav Самое первое предложение в моем вопросе говорит, я изучаю unity на основе pixel art игры, а не начал еще ее делать. А то, что там сейчас не целые координаты я думал для моих конкретно заданных вопросов не так важно, я хочу, чтобы мне пояснили их так как понятного ответа в гугле я не нашел.

Comment: Не в гугле нужно искать. Документация есть https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-pixelsPerUnit.html